# Issue with the .currentTime JS property

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with .currentTime properties, the thing is that I want the video play smoothly on scroll.
The thing is that it's working, but only when I scroll, go to another window and come back on the window.

Here is my code

Thanks by advance :)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <video id="video" muted paused controls>
        <source src="index_video_sd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

</body>

<script>
    let vid = document.getElementById('video');
    setInterval(function() {
        vid.currentTime = window.pageYOffset / 1000;
        console.log(vid.currentTime);
        console.log(window.pageYOffset / 1000);
    })
</script>

</html>
```

CSS

```
video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

body {
    min-height: 10000px;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: The thing is that the animation is not on live when I scroll, its when I go to another window and go back to the window. I would like to have something like that https://www.apple.com/fr/airpods-pro/ (first animation)